# Magento 2 : How to generate a collection from data models

Tags: magento2, collection, data

If I understand correctly, Magento 2 moves more and more to the strict use of data models instead of creating models that are tied-in with their resource models and have all kind of business logic that, well... just are not within the responsibility of those models.

You can see this shift by looking at the naming used for the service contracts: `Api/Data/xxxInterface` are interfaces for data models. If you look at the customer module you can see the related data models in `Model/Data/*`. These are models that extend from `AbstractExtensibleObject`, which in it turn extends `Magento\Framework\Api\AbstractSimpleObject`.

Please, if anything if the above is mis-assumption or incorrect, please tell me what the proper Magento 2 philosophy is.

Now ...

I'm trying to create a module that uses solely data models and UI Components to generate the list and the form etc. This works fine, but as soon as I have to be able to create a collection, I have to provide a model that extends from `Magento\Framework\DataObject`. This is set in the `_init()` method of `Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection`:

```
/**
 * Define resource model
 */
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init(
        'Vendor\Module\Model\Data\Foo',
        'Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Foo'
    );
}
```

Now, if I do this, I get the exception:

```
Vendor\Module\Model\Data\Foo does not extend \Magento\Framework\DataObject
```

Which makes sense, because data models extend from `Magento\Framework\Api\AbstractSimpleObject`.

Now I don't want to create a dummy model just for this, that doesn't seem right, so I peeked how this is handled in the framework itself in `Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult`. This is a class that is used as a `virtualType` in `di.xml` and provides a collection for the listing. And like I said, that worked. So how did they pull this off?

Well it looked like they did:

```
$this->_init($this->document, $resourceModel);
```

And `$this->document` is the name of `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document`, which in it's turn extends `\Magento\Framework\DataObject`.

So with this knowledge, I edited my own collection like this:

```
/**
 * Define resource model
 */
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document::class,
        'Happy\PrivateDownloads\Model\ResourceModel\Download'
    );
}
```

And now it works.

But, just because it works doesn't necessarily mean that this is the correct solution. So that's why I'm asking this question in the community:

*Is this the proper way to create collections from data models?*

Any answer / help / insights would be greatly appreciated!